# not able to pass column values from cursor variable to select query

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE record_AB AS OBJECT
   (
      AA    VARCHAR2 (32767 BYTE),
      BB    VARCHAR2 (32767 BYTE)
   );
    /

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_tab_AB IS TABLE OF record_AB;
    /


SQL> VARIABLE curs1 REFCURSOR;
SQL> 
SQL> DECLARE
  2  tab_AB   type_tab_AB;
  3  begin
  4  select  system.record_AB(t.owner,t.table_name) bulk collect into tab_AB from dba_tables t where compression='ENABLED' and compress_for='OLTP';
  5  open :curs1 for select * from table(tab_AB) ;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from dba_segments where (owner,segment_name) in ( select :curs1 from dual);
select * from dba_segments where (owner,segment_name) in ( select :curs1 from dual)

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00947: not enough values
```

I need to provide the values of aa, bb columns of cursor curs1 as input for owner and segment_name , Can someone please tell us how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a cursor variable, you can only open, fetch and close it.  What are you trying to achieve really? There is no need to use a ref cursor here at all:

```
select * from dba_segments 
where (owner,segment_name) in 
( select t.owner,t.table_name 
  from dba_tables t 
  where compression='ENABLED' 
  and compress_for='OLTP');
```

However if the purpose of your code is to play with ref cursors, rather than view segment data, then this answer may not be what you want.

Using a table:

```
create table enabled_oltp_tables as
select t.owner,t.table_name 
from dba_tables t 
where compression='ENABLED' 
and compress_for='OLTP';

select * from dba_segments 
where (owner,segment_name) in 
( select t.owner,t.table_name 
  from enabled_oltp_tables t
);
```

Comment: My requriment is to compare the sizes of the segments before and after uncompression . So i am trying to store  the list of compressed segments (owner and segment names) in a cursor variable .After uncompression , i need to get the the sizes of those segments . We can't use your code bcos after uncompression "select t.owner,t.table_name 
  from dba_tables t 
  where compression='ENABLED' 
  and compress_for='OLTP'"  this will not result any rows

Comment: Why not just save them to a table?

Comment: Thanks Tony .This is a one time task so we are trying not to use table . Is there any other way ?

Comment: You can drop the table afterwards?  Same as you are creating and will presumably drop a TYPE currently.  If you can do all the work in a single PL/SQL program then you can remember the segment names in a collection.

Comment: Tony, can you send me the sample code using the table for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

> Hi. Just went through the question. Thought you can give a try like
>   this. Let me know if this helps

```
--Create object type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE record_AB
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    AA VARCHAR2 (32767 BYTE),
    BB VARCHAR2 (32767 BYTE) );

--Create table type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_tab_AB
IS
  TABLE OF record_AB;

--Plsql block to perform action 
  var ref_c refcursor;
  DECLARE
    tab_AB type_tab_AB;
  BEGIN
    SELECT record_AB(t.owner,t.table_name) bulk collect
    INTO tab_AB
    FROM all_tables t
    WHERE compression='ENABLED';
    OPEN :ref_c FOR SELECT * FROM dba_segments WHERE (owner,segment_name) IN
    ( SELECT t.aa,t.bb FROM TABLE(tab_AB) t
    );
  END;

  Print ref_c;
```